# Weird path situation in Laravel. Why is this working?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm working on some Laravel code in PHPStorm and I just noticed a weird path problem. Looking at the project directory

[image]

it's obvious the path to my models is `App\Models` but if you look at the code, the path is `App\Http\Models`. If I change the code to use `App\Model`, PHPStorm complains that it can't find the model, and when I run the code I get the same error.

I've looked throughout my code and this is the case everywhere.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `namespace` section in your model files.

It should point to

```
namespace App\Models
```

and not to

```
namespace App\Http\Models
```